# C# List doesn't get updated

Tags: c#

I am pretty new to C# and I have the issue below. I have this list here MasterFireList but it doesn't get updated and the length is always 1. And when I try to delete the item, only the last item get's deleted.

```
        public static List<FireEx> MasterFireList = new List<FireEx>();
        private static FireEx[] CreatedFires;
        internal static Vector3[] FireLocations = new Vector3[1];


        public static void CreateFires(bool IsGasFire)
        {
            FireLocations[0] = Game.LocalPlayer.Character.GetOffsetPositionFront(1f);

            CreatedFires = Util.CreateFires(FireLocations);


            foreach (FireEx f in CreatedFires)
            {
                f.Fire.DesiredBurnDuration = 30.0f;
                f.Fire.SpreadRadius = 2.0f;
                MasterFireList.Add(f);
            }

            Game.LogTrivial($"CreatedFires Length: {CreatedFires.Length}");
        }

        public static void DeleteFires()
        {
            if (MasterFireList != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < CreatedFires.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (CreatedFires[i].Fire)
                    {
                        CreatedFires[i].Fire.Delete();
                        MasterFireList.RemoveAt(i);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
```

Added the CreateFires, the issue should be inside here but I can't figure it out yet.

```
        public static FireEx[] CreateFires(Vector3[] positions, int maxChildren, bool isGasFire, bool bigFires, bool onGround = true)
        {
            uint[] handles = new uint[positions.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < positions.Length; i++)
            {
                Vector3 p = positions[i];
                if (onGround)
                {
                    float? z = World.GetGroundZ(p, false, true);
                    if (z.HasValue)
                    {
                        p.Z = z.Value;
                        positions[i].Z = z.Value;
                    }
                }

                handles[i] = NativeFunction.Natives.StartScriptFire<uint>(p.X, p.Y, p.Z, maxChildren, isGasFire);
            }

            FireEx[] fires = World.GetAllFires().Where(f => positions.Contains(f.Position)).Select(f => (bigFires ? new BigFireEx(handles[Array.IndexOf(positions, f.Position)], f) : new FireEx(handles[Array.IndexOf(positions, f.Position)], f))).ToArray();
            return fires;
        }
```

Comment: Do you want to delete all of the items from the list? You can use the `MasterFireList.Clear()` function to do that in the `DeleteFires` function after you've checked whether `MasterFireList` is empty (null) or not. If that's not the case, could you edit your question to give more details as to what you're trying to accomplish? Thanks! :)

Comment: This is a good time to learn to use the debugger.  Put a breakpoint on the line where you call `Util.CreateFires(FireLocations);` and then step a bit.  Check to see what `CreatedFires` looks like and what `MasterFireList` looks like each time it runs.  Figure things out from there.  You haven't really posted enough code for us to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

Evidently this loop executes 1 time only:

```
            foreach (FireEx f in CreatedFires)
            {
                f.Fire.DesiredBurnDuration = 30.0f;
                f.Fire.SpreadRadius = 2.0f;
                MasterFireList.Add(f);
            }
```

It causes MasterFireList consists of 1 element only.

Comment: Hello, yes this might be the issue. I execute the CreateFires when I press a button. So the loop shouldn't be played again and then the mastefirelist get an another item?

Comment: I guess 'CreatedFires = Util.CreateFires(FireLocations);' just assign CreatedFires the same again and again.

Comment: I added the CreateFires function to the main post.

Comment: Everything is still unclear, too few information. Did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting into the list *MasterFireList* the same references (but updated) contained in *CreatedFires*. So in the end, they will have the same size. Therefore, I suggest looking at what happens in `Util.CreateFires(FireLocations);`.

The method **List.Add(T item)** adds an item to the end of the list. A List is implemented with an array.
At a high level, when a list is created, an array with a certain size is created under the hood, and then there will be a variable that will keep count of how many elements are actually there. This will be incremented with each insertion. When the array is full, a new one is created with double the size and all the references are copied over.

In the deletion, the check `MasterFireList != null` is useless since you initialize it there.
Perhaps `CreatedFires != null` would make more sense if the method *DeleteFires()* is called before *CreateFires()*.

Comment: I added the CreateFires function to the main post. That's the issue probably, but I still can't figure it out.

Comment: The cardinality of the array `fires` depends on how many elements in `GetAllFires()` satisfy `positions.Contains(f.Position)`.
So, check how many and which elements are there in `GetAllFires()` and in `positions`.
I can assume that in `GetAllFires()` there is only one element that has the position included in the array `positions` and therefore satisfies the predicate in the `Where()` method.